# closed form solution to best invertible matrix which minimizes product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization

Let $U, X \in \mathbb{R}^{n_1 \times r}$ and let $V, Y \in \mathbb{R}^{n_2 \times r}$. Consider the optimization problem
$$
\begin{align*}
  \min_{A, B, \Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times r}} \left\{ \| U A \Sigma B^T - X \|_F^2 + \| V A \Sigma^{-1} B^T - Y \|_F^2 \right\} \\
\mathrm{subj. to} \;\;A^TA = B^TB = I, \Sigma \; \mathrm{diagonal}, \Sigma \succ 0
\end{align*}
$$
I'm wondering if there is an easy closed form solution for this problem. I tried writing out the Lagrangian and taking derivatives w.r.t. $A$ and $B$ but nothing immediately jumped out at me.